# urllib2 in Python 2.6.4: Any way to override windows hosts file?

Tags: python, windows, ip, urllib2, hosts

I am using the urllib2 module in Python 2.6.4, running in Windows XP, to access a URL. I am making a post request, that does not involve cookies or https or anything too complicated. The domain is redirected in my C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file. However, I would like the request from urllib2 to go to the "real" domain and ignore the entry in the hosts file. Is there any easy and practical way to do this?

<strike>I would prefer if the request has the domain name in it, for example:</strike>

```
GET www.example.com/foo.html
```

rather than

```
GET 123.45.67.89/foo.html
```

Forget about that last part if you want. I don't need to be that specific about what goes in the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect to the IP address and pass the `Host` header manually.

Comment: But how would you know the IP? (Assuming it's not hardcoded - or is it?) You can't use a regular gethostbyname call, since that again uses the hosts file...

Comment: You could use a separate DNS client to find it ... of course, that leads directly to the question: what DNS server?

Comment: What if the domain name needs to go in the request header? See my edit.

Comment: For a separate DNS client, see dnspython.

Comment: That's kind of clever... How does it work for protocols like HTTPS?

Comment: @jww it works unless you care about SSL checks.  The requester will see that the cert for example.com doesn't match an IP address and will fail.